# Firefox 74.0 (64-bit) Amazon Music Library keeps saying browser not supported

Tags: firefox, 64-bit, amazon

Firefox 74.0 (64-bit) Amazon Music Library keeps saying browser not supported please upgrade to latest version. I am on the latest version though Firefox 74.0 (64-bit). I've removed and re-installed firefox multiple times. Are there other non standard plugins, extensions or library files I need to install as well?

Comment: Go to Firefox preferences at General/Network Connections/Settings and turn off "Enable DNS over HTTPS" and see if that helps. Have you installed any extensions that allow you to report that Firefox is acting as a different browser? Report back.